# Using flash inside a native iOS app

Tags: ios, animation, flash

I'm working on a native Objective-C iOS app and I'm wondering if it is possible to embed an animation created in Flash into my app. The animation doesn't have to be interactive, all I need is a couple of animated screens (intro screen, loading screen). Is this posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the long way around since it doesn't sound like you need a Flash-heavy type app but I have seen a few Flash-toCocoa2D exporters around. I haven't got around to trying them yet but they look useful. Of course you probably have to be using the Cocoa2D frame work to use them - unless there is an easy way to extract + repurpose that relevant code from the Cocoa2D source.

Anyway, probably overkill for what you need but here are some links:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/514219/FlashToCocos2dAnimation.zip

VID of it in action:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZyqGrdkTtM

Another tool:
http://marshgames.com/swftoxml-and-importing-flash-scenes-into-cocos2d-on-iphone/

Comment: This looks very promising! I'm going to check this and let you know if it works.

Comment: the VID's link is broken.

Comment: so is the other tool's link (marshgames etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Nope...Apple will reject any app that uses flash

you could use video player for intro screen (i've seen it on a few apps) or simple picture animation using UIView animation methods

[here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial) is a tutorial

Comment: Are there tools/IDE to create a native vector animation for iOS?

Comment: well..yea...the iOS core graphics (aka quartz 2d) but if you're coming from an actionscript background why not use Adobe Air to develop apps?

Comment: I'm not coming from an actionscript background, but I know that a simple vector animation can be created in Flash easily, that's why I was thinking of using it.

Comment: yes i'm with Andrey on this being easy and simple on Flash rather than hard coding on Objective-C. Actually i'm not good with Flash bit I've seen how ppl doing stuff easy by Flash. In Windows Phone 8 you have Blend IDE to do animation (keyframes, ease,etc.) and it works ver well! I hope we could have something like that timeline to create animations not that complex but simple and easy like with Silverlight (XAML) in Microsoft Blend. Anyway, converting flash to cocoas 2D sounds promising Andrey, did you get anywhere with this question?